# Turbo C++ linker warning: No module definition specified

Tags: c, turbo-c++

What is the meaning of the warning in Turbo C++ compiler:

```
Linking *.exe:
Linker Warning: No module definition file specified: using defaults
```

Comment: Turbo C++? What version? Version 4.0 was released in 1993, nearly 20 years old now. Upgrade to a real compiler? Intel, Microsoft, GCC, LLVM all have free compilers that are vastly superior in most respects.

Comment: What school is it that is using Turbo C++ in their education ?

Answer (score 1):

A [Module Definition File](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/28d6s79h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) provides the linker with information about exports, attributes, and other information about the program to be linked.

You probably don't need to use one.